# MYSQL Truncated incorrect DOUBLE while using double and single quotation marks

Tags: mysql, triggers, quotation-marks, mysql-error-1292

I'm created a trigger that inserts a row in a table after a row is deleted in another table.

Here's my trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_delete_log_animal AFTER delete ON animal
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO log_animais (momento, ocorrencia)
    VALUES (now(), "The register '" + old.nome_animal + "' was deleted from the animal table");
```

I want nome_animal to be between single quotation marks.

But I get the following error when I delete a row from the animal table:

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'The register ''
```

I've tried changing it to

```
'The register "' + old.nome_animal + '" was deleted from the animal table'
```

And also to

```
"The register \'" + old.nome_animal + "\' was deleted from the animal table"
```

But it's no good.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to build strings with + in your SQL code.

Use [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) instead:

```sql
 VALUES (now(), CONCAT(
           'The register \'', 
            old.nome_animal, 
            '\' was deleted from the animal table'));
```

And, escape the `'` characters you want in your strings with `\`.

```
'Mrs. O\'Leary\'s cow.'
```